# How Can I Run an Infinite Loop from a Bash Script with Output to Foreground

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

So, I want to run the below command from a bash script and have it output to the shell, however, all my attempts result in the script running in the background:

```
while [ 1 ]; do timeout -k9 21600 sngrep -c -O "/var/log/sngrep/sngrep_capture_$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).pcap"; sleep 1; done
```

When I run the command directly in the shell prompt, it outputs as expected.  The application, SNGREP, launches with the specified parameters and works well.

I have experimented with sending the command to Screen, but it still ends up in the background.  I have also tried modifying the command by sleeping first (as follows):

```
while sleep 1; do timeout -k9 21600 sngrep -c -O "/var/log/sngrep/sngrep_capture_$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).pcap"; done
```

It, too, goes to the background but then runs fine if I type it directly into the shell prompt.  What else can I try to get the command to output to the foreground when run from a bash script?  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**PS.**  *My end goal is to launch SNGREP in a Putty window from a Windows Batch File.  I've got everything working, but this last bit.*

Comment: Please use `while true` or `while :`

Comment: i tried that but still running in background

Comment: Not a solution but a recommendation

Comment: oh okay.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your command why it is running in background, rather it should run on foreground only. You can try with below, redirect(2>&1) the output to standard output always:-

```
  while [ 1 ]; do timeout -k9 21600 sngrep -c -O "/var/log/sngrep/sngrep_capture_$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).pcap" 2>&1; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt, but it did not work.  Script still run in background